# how to call this variable in my array editcase

Tags: php

I have a session called `$_SESSION['data']`

And I have a text input called 'lengtezijde'

I already used foreach on the session:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $key => $data);
```

And if I want to use my input from lengtezijde, I tried it like this:

```
echo $_SESSION['data'][$_GET['key'];
```

but then it is an array and I want the input value.

How do I go a layer deeper in the array to use the value?

Comment: Input value are passed via POST

Comment: Do one thing `print_r($_SESSION['data'])` and see the data structure.

Comment: Your last echo is missing a `]`

Comment: @GufranHasan the output is than `Array ( [0] => Array ( [hoogte] => 1 [kleur] => 1 [lengtezijde] => 800 [toevoegen] => toevoegen ) ) `

Comment: Okay, @snakepyro, `print_r($data)` inside loop.

Comment: _“How do I go a layer deeper in the array”_ - why do you _have_ that extra “layer” in the first place? Why did you not add those items directly to `$_SESSION['data']` under their respective key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this inside the foreach loop:

```
echo $data['lengtezijde'];
```

or

```
echo $_SESSION['data'][$key]['lengtezijde'];
```

We have seen `$key` will have indexing value `0`.

**Note:**  as looping on session data you will get `$data` value as when print `$data`:

```
Array ( [hoogte] => 1 [kleur] => 1 [lengtezijde] => 800 [toevoegen] => toevoegen )
```

So you can get directly the value of `lengtezijde` by using as :

`$data['lengtezijde'];` inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ....

```
echo $_SESSION['data'][$key]['lengtezijde'];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you set the value of the array. If you set the array value in the for-loop like this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['data'] as $key => $data);
    $data['lengtezijde'] = "some value";
```

Then to get the value you must do something like this:

```
$key = $_GET['key']; //or the key to the index you want
echo $_SESSION['data'][$key]['lengtezijde'];
```